# Trying to join 3 mysql tables but I do not get the expected result. What is mistake?

Tags: php, mysql

The below mysql query

```
SELECT *
FROM alerts_list l, alerts_data d, alerts_push_data p
WHERE p.push_data_hash = d.alerts_data_hash
AND p.push_data_alert_id = l.alerts_id
AND d.alerts_data_id = l.alerts_id
AND d.alerts_data_hash =  'JiaYRSVNZxgE'
```

shows the results of `JiaYRSVNZxgE` by joining three tables.

Here are the tables that I use and the columns that I want to connect between them:

**table alerts_list**

column: `alerts_id`

[image]

**table alerts_push_data**

column: `push_data_alert_id`

column: `push_data_hash`

[image]

**table alerts_data**

column: `alerts_data_id`

column: `alerts_data_hash`

[image]

**What I want to achieve is:**

connect `push_data_alert_id` with `alerts_id`

connect `alerts_data_id` with `alerts_id`

but show only the results where `alerts_data_hash` and `push_data_hash` is `"abcdef"`

Unfortunately my query results to no results found, but there are results in reality.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Without the data you expect to provide results, there is not much that can be suggested. Other than to stop using the `,` "join" notation; it makes such queries much much harder to read, make sense of, and guess at intent.

Comment: Can we assume all the id fields used are integers?

Comment: @Uueerdo yes all re integers. double checked them now.

Comment: In case you missed the comment I left under Poiz's answer. I think I can now see why your original query returns nothing; the rows that share hashes match to different alerts_list rows. No results is the correct result for the query you've shown. What are your expected results?

Answer (score 2):

You could use MySQL JOINS to perform that operation quite easily like so:

```
         <?php
            // USING NORMAL JOIN:
            // WE NOW ADD AN EXTRA LAYER (THE VARIABLE $fldVal) 
            // IN THE CASE THAT YOUR VALUE ('JiaYRSVNZxgE') IS DYNAMIC...
            $fldVal = 'JiaYRSVNZxgE';
            $sql    = "SELECT DISTINCT *
                            FROM alerts_list l 
                            JOIN alerts_data d ON d.alerts_data_id=l.alerts_id
                            JOIN alerts_push_data p ON p.push_data_alert_id=l.alerts_id
                            WHERE d.alerts_data_hash='" . $fldVal . "'";



            // USING LEFT JOIN:
            // WE NOW ADD AN EXTRA LAYER (THE VARIABLE $fldVal) 
            // IN THE CASE THAT YOUR VALUE ('JiaYRSVNZxgE') IS DYNAMIC...
            $fldVal = 'JiaYRSVNZxgE';
            $sql    = "SELECT DISTINCT *
                            FROM alerts_list l 
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_data d ON d.alerts_data_id=l.alerts_id
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_push_data p ON p.push_data_alert_id=l.alerts_id
                            WHERE d.alerts_data_hash='" . $fldVal . "'";



            // USING INNER JOIN:
            // WE NOW ADD AN EXTRA LAYER (THE VARIABLE $fldVal) 
            // IN THE CASE THAT YOUR VALUE ('JiaYRSVNZxgE') IS DYNAMIC...
            $fldVal = 'JiaYRSVNZxgE';
            $sql    = "SELECT DISTINCT *
                            FROM alerts_list l 
                            INNER JOIN alerts_data d ON d.alerts_data_id=l.alerts_id
                            INNER JOIN alerts_push_data p ON p.push_data_alert_id=l.alerts_id
                            WHERE d.alerts_data_hash='" . $fldVal . "'";
```

**::AND YET A NEW UPDATE WITH GROUP BY CLAUSE::**

```
        <?php
            // WE NOW ADD AN EXTRA LAYER (THE VARIABLE $fldVal) 
            // IN THE CASE THAT YOUR VALUE ('JiaYRSVNZxgE') IS DYNAMIC...
            $fldVal = 'JiaYRSVNZxgE';



            $sql2    = "SELECT DISTINCT *
                            FROM alerts_list AS A_LIST
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_push_data A_PUSH ON A_PUSH.push_data_alert_id=A_LIST.alerts_id
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_data A_DATA ON A_DATA.alerts_data_hash=A_PUSH.push_data_hash
                            WHERE A_DATA.alerts_data_hash='" . $fldVal . "'
                            GROUP BY A_LIST.alerts_id";
```

**TEST-CASE QUERY**

```
                    SELECT DISTINCT *
                            FROM alerts_list AS A_LIST
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_push_data A_PUSH ON A_PUSH.push_data_alert_id=A_LIST.alerts_id
                            LEFT JOIN alerts_data A_DATA ON A_DATA.alerts_data_hash=A_PUSH.push_data_hash
                            WHERE A_DATA.alerts_data_hash='iSg2loGJDaWs'
                            GROUP BY A_LIST.alerts_id
```

**RESULT**

And these are to be expected because I simulated only 2 Rows in all the other Tables except the *alerts_list* which has 10 Rows.

**Result of dumping the Query Above** 
[image: var_dump using the Query Above]

**Table: alerts_list**

[image: Table: alerts_list]

**Table: alerts_data**
[image: Table: alerts_data]

**Table: alerts_push_data**
[image: Table: alerts_push_data]